# Loading in python - showing progress

Tags: python

I need something like this:

```
Loading.
```

After it prints in same position:

```
Loading..
```

Then

```
Loading...
```

I know this is might be a repeated question but `\r` and `\b` and sys are not working in the Python shell because I develop in the shell, so please give me working code for the shell.

Comment: Can you add code so we can see what you have tried so far? This will make it less likely that your question gets removed because people will see that you've made a good faith effort

Comment: Why do you need it to be done in the python shell? I think you need to give a good reason for it. The python shell is for development, but when you will use the script later I should work as you want with sys to overwrite the line.

Comment: As suggested in one of the answers, use tqmd library

Comment: already did since its working and if not shell then on wht should i work best terminal for windows 8.1 can u tell?

Comment: add  your progress

Comment: @Newbie_coder_15 I think you should look into change shell, the shell you use seems to be very bad. If it was not for the shell I think your solution probably worked from the start.

Comment: its python shell idle

Comment: `\r` not works in Python Shell (as well as some other features). Consider going to a better environment (better would be if you will execute your code in terminal).

Comment: can u tell which terminal i just install sublime but my code is not running on it any more terminal?

Comment: @Newbie_coder_15 Sublime is a text editor, not a terminal.

Comment: which terminal should i use?

Comment: Almost any other shell, I recommend you to use pycharm or visual code (IDE) and use the shell they give you.

Comment: "NOTICE FOR STAFF: Please dont delete this question you guys had removed my 2 previous question so please dont remove since i really need a working answer."—I sympathize, but we have rules here. The best way to get useful answers isn't to beg the community not to delete your question, but to ask a _good_ one. There are some great guidelines on our [ask] page. Also check out [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) if you have time to read that much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain python.

```py
print('Loading', end='')

for _ in range(10):
    print('.', end='')
```

Or use [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) library. From the README.md available, you can execute it with shell using pipes.

```
$ seq 9999999 | tqdm --bytes | wc -l
75.2MB [00:00, 217MB/s]
9999999

$ tar -zcf - docs/ | tqdm --bytes --total `du -sb docs/ | cut -f1` \
    > backup.tgz
 32%|██████████▍                      | 8.89G/27.9G [00:42<01:31, 223MB/s]
```

Comment: does tqdm work in shell i think its for terminal?

Comment: Is it possible to add "loading completed" here?

Comment: @Newbie_coder_15 edited my answer for shell support. Does it answer your question ? Consider upvote and accept the answer if it helped you !

Comment: should i install tqdm?

Comment: yes, follow the instructions from https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#installation for your platform

Answer (score 1):

I realize you can do it like this to get what you want:

````
>>> from time import sleep
>>> print("loading.\r",end='');sleep(1);print("loading..\r", end='');sleep(1);print("loading...")
loading...
>>>
```
````

Comment: idk how but the output is 'loading.loading..loading..'

Comment: This solution also allows you to write something else in the end like "loading completed".

Comment: @Newbie_coder_15 No, the \r should remove return to beginng of the line. I tried on my windows machine there it was correct.
I also tried here: https://www.python.org/shell/

Comment: might be but its not working on mine shell

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: python idle shell 3.8.5

Comment: yeah i know that and i had said in question also that \r is not working in shell any termnal name?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

```
import time 

print('Loading.')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading..')
time.sleep(1)
print('Loading...')
```

If you wanna do this more professionally
just check this thread
[Python how to make simple animated loading while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029562/python-how-to-make-simple-animated-loading-while-process-is-running)

Comment: bro thanks for helping out but your code is running like this-: Loading. Loading.. in next line i need in one line